# MVC Append "#" to the querystring

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tabs

I struggle with something really simple... help? 
I want to do the following:
I have two pages with tabs (JQuery) and I want to remember the tab selection. I decided to use the query string in order to achieve that, but switching between pages I don't know how to pass the tab. 
Example: I have an url http://localhost/Object/Edit/1#tab_tax1

And I have my link to the other page:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink(Resource.Details, "Details", new { id = Model.Object.ID })%>
```

I want to pass somehow the "#tab_tax1" so I keep the selection in the other page too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using action link compose only the url inside the href of the "a" tag:

```
Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Details", id = Model.Object.ID }) + "#tab_tax1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You use JQuery tabs, so that means you can use the cookies. Then you don't really need to append the tab to the url, because it is stored in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragement parameter.

```
Html.ActionLink(Resource.Details, "Details", controllerName, Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, "tab_tax1", null, null)
```

Hope this help.